# How to access res.groups model in Odoo Mobile framework

Tags: android, odoo, odoo-mobile

I am creating an application using Odoo Mobile Framework. How can I get the information of the roles of the connected user? It is possible for me to get the table res.groups from that framework?

Answer (score 0):

res.group model is already in there in framework so all you have to do is modify that model if you don't find your fields in that model and after that just run the select query for the model.